# Order status showing pending instead of cancel in magento 2

Tags: magento2

Order status is not changing after order cancel still showing pending in order status grid.

For reference see screenshot url.

http://nimb.ws/n1L7qi

http://nimb.ws/W0Hmzp

Comment: did you apply the «Submit comment» button, or just changed select box value? You can also use «cancel» button on the top of the order view page and cancel mass action on the orders grid page

Comment: I have canceled the order from the top button on order view page.

Comment: Please, check Advanced/Developer/Grid Settings: Asynchronous Indexing. Try to disable it and clear cache. And do you have cron jobs running?

Comment: It's already disabled.